# Reactjs BigCalendar Adding Event

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using BigCalendar and I am trying to add an event. Currently, in github they use window.prompt(); but I would like to use Modal. However, nothing is appearing and I am unsure why.

link: https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar

render:

```
  return(
    <div style={{ height: 700 }}>
      <BigCalendar
        selectable={true}
        localizer={localizer}
        events={this.state.cal_events}
        step={30}
        defaultView='month'
        views={['month','week','day']}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
        onSelectEvent={event => alert(event.title)}
        onSelectSlot={this.handleSelect}
      />        
    </div>
  );
```

handleSelect (where user click on a date to add an event)

```
handleSelect = e => {
  //set model to true
this.openModal();
  return(
   <div> 
    <Modal
      isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
      onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
      onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
      contentLabel="Example Modal"
    >

      <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
      <div>Add event</div>
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <input />
        <DropdownButton title={this.state.dropDownSelection} key="1" id="test" onSelect={this.onchangeSelectDropdown} >
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option  1"> Option 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option 2"> Option 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option 3"> Option 3</MenuItem>

          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey="Other">Other</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </Modal>
  </div> 
  );

}
```

The problem is that Model never renders and I am unsure why. If this way is not possible are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that Model never renders and I am unsure why

It's because the returned `Modal` component was never attached to the DOM.

Try changing your implementation by conditionally rendering the `Modal` instead.

```js
handleSelect = e => {
  //set model to true
  this.setState({
    modalIsOpen: true
  });
}

renderModal = () => {
  if (!this.state.modalIsOpen) return;
  return(
    <Modal
      isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
      onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
      onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
      contentLabel="Example Modal"
    >

      <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
      <div>Add event</div>
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <input />
        <DropdownButton title={this.state.dropDownSelection} key="1" id="test" onSelect={this.onchangeSelectDropdown} >
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option  1"> Option 1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option 2"> Option 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="Option 3"> Option 3</MenuItem>

          <MenuItem divider />
          <MenuItem eventKey="Other">Other</MenuItem>
        </DropdownButton>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 700 }}>
      <BigCalendar
        selectable={true}
        localizer={localizer}
        events={this.state.cal_events}
        step={30}
        defaultView="month"
        views={["month", "week", "day"]}
        defaultDate={new Date()}
        scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
        onSelectEvent={event => alert(event.title)}
        onSelectSlot={this.handleSelect}
      />
      <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      {this.renderModal()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

See minimal working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/50j9zx7knn

Comment: Its still not rendering anything inside the return statement. I wonder if its even  possible?

Comment: Are you sure that `handleSelect` is called when you select a date, can you try console logging it and let me know.

Comment: Yes because I have a console log on renderModal which gets printed

Comment: Okay, can you show me the full component code in fiddle, pen, etc so we can check what's happening.

Comment: I have added the link on my question.Let me know if you can find something I can't

Comment: I edited the answer and added minimal working example.